# Sort order of New Users tab by reputation

Tags: support, status-bydesign, new-users, sorting

This is really minor, but the sort order is backwards when viewing new users by reputation. Since its focus is on *new* users, you'd expect those with the lowest rep to be first, but it actually shows the highest first (within its definition of "new").

Comment: I think its *real* focus is on highlighting "new users who look like they're going to contribute substantially to the community", which would make the sort order a bit more reasonable. That's just speculation on my part, though.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a bug to me... I'm pretty sure it's by design to highlight those new users that have earned the most reputation quickly.

Comment: It would be nice though to see the newest users who *don't* earn rep quickly, because they might need a little help getting their answers right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is intentional, we are indeed highlighting new users who are contributing the most to the community.