# Finding potential new users based on reputation from answers?

Tags: support, reputation, answers, data-explorer, new-users

Is it a good idea to show reputation without the +100 association bonus, in the [new user's tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=newusers)?

Specifically in smaller sites, not only would it be easier to visualize [who is contributing the most to the community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103318/sort-order-of-new-users-tab-by-reputation), but it also would facilitate the tracking of [good recent answers which sometimes takes awhile to get visibility](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/are-there-other-ways-to-find-good-recent-answers-on-crossvalidated/1755#1755).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Stack Exchange Data Explorer I wrote a query for helping emphasize potential new answerers:

[Answer reputation rank from new users](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/968211/answer-reputation-rank-from-new-users?days=30)

The query returns a rank of top 10 new users* measured by **reputation earned only in answers** (+upvotes, +accepts, +bounties, -downvotes). This means it leaves everything else out (bonus association, rep from questions, rep from suggested edits, downvotes casted, bounties offered, etc.).

*New users are defined to be the ones in their first 'n' days in Stack Exchange, where 'n' is a parameter in the query.

Besides reputation from answers, it shows:

- Count of answers, requiring at least  two answers.
- Answer reputation rate (total reputation from answers divided by the number of answers).
- Proportion of the top answer's reputation in relation to total answer reputation (in %).
- Proportion of reputation from bounties in relation to total answer reputation (in %).

All auxiliary columns have the objective of providing a better summary from new potential answer contributors to Stack Exchange. The **objective** of this query is to provide a more complete way (than the [new users tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=newusers)) to find, monitor and interact in a positive way with such users.

Here are some examples from today (8-Feb-2019):

- In Stack Overflow, considering new users in their first 30 days of Stack Exchange, user [taka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10936865/taka) ranked 1st in the query, earning 1096 reputation points in 34 answers, being 68.4% (750 rep) of them from bounties. Practically, a bounty hunter here.
- In Cross Validated, considering new users with up to 1 year in Stack Exchange, user [Brent Hutto](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/227039/brent-hutto?tab=answers&sort=votes) ranked 7th with approximately 1k rep from answers, with 85.5% coming from his top answer, i.e., a successful hit. On the other hand, user [Isabella Ghement](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/200312/isabella-ghement?tab=answers&sort=votes&page=4) who ranked first had only ~10% from her total answer reputation coming from bounties or her top answer. Looking at her profile we can see that almost all her answers (except 2) are positively scored.

---

With the many pending [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) in Stack Exchange, I believe we can now turn this to a [support](/questions/tagged/support) question.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe they should create a separate tab for **new active users**.